# PHP Poll and Values

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to php, and i'm trying to create a poll. Each answer has a value (from 0 to 3) and i when i press "submit" i want a different message to appear for a different result. If the sum of the values is  0-4, for example, i want it to appear a message. If it's 5-9, a different message.

```
<label><span class="badge">1</span>Do you like this website?</label>
<p>
  <label>No</label>
  <input type="radio" name="poll" value="0"><br/>
  <label>Maybe</label>
  <input type="radio" name="poll" value="1"><br/>
  <label>I don't know</label>
  <input type="radio" name="poll" value="2"><br/>
  <label>Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="poll" value="3"><br/>
</p>
<input type="button" class="btn-danger" id="btn" value="Submit">
```

This is my html. I can only find examples with a database.Thanks!

Comment: did you already try something??

Comment: where is your form ?? or do you want to do with js??

Comment: Was my answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to add a poll system, but without the integration of a database to store each vote.

This is a problem if you want people from different computers to be able to vote on the same page. Without a database, you can really only store each vote locally with Javascript. So all users would have to use the poll on the same browser, and without refreshing the page.

If that's what you want, then you could do something like this:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6k3yjuyp/)

```
var sum = 0;
var count = 0;
var avg = 0;

$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    count++;
    sum = +sum + +$('input[name=poll]:checked').val();
    avg = sum / count;
    $("#print").html("The average is: " + avg + ", and the sum is: " + sum);
    if(sum < 5) {
        alert("The sum is below 5!");
    } else {
        alert("The sum is above 5!");
    }
});
```

Note that I used jQuery here, but it can be done without.

EDIT: The alerts should say "sum" and not "average".

EDIT 2: php approach - single vote only - without database:

**HTML**

```
<form action="process_vote.php" method="post">
  <label><span class="badge">1</span>Do you like this website?</label>
  <p>
    <label>No</label>
    <input type="radio" name="poll" value="no"><br/>
    <label>Maybe</label>
    <input type="radio" name="poll" value="maybe"><br/>
    <label>I don't know</label>
    <input type="radio" name="poll" value="I don't know"><br/>
    <label>Yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="poll" value="yes"><br/>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" class="btn-danger" id="btn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

   $var = $_POST['poll'];

   echo "The user voted: $var";
?>
```

Comment: Hello and Thank you. I don't use a database because i don't need to store the values. The poll is only used by the user so that he can see the end result. Like those polls from "Which disney character are you?" xD. Can it be done in php? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you want php?

Comment: It was to train the code. But if it's not possible, no problem. Do i have to create a new file.js for this code?

Comment: The problem doing it with php is that you will only be able to vote once, unless you use a database. But yeah, technically it can be done.

Comment: that wouldn't be a problem

Comment: I added the php version. Note that this will only take the vote from the html page and print the option out. Since you can only vote once this way, there is no point in doing calculations for sum and average. The php code is the `process_vote.php` file.